# How do I randomize a list of strings with random.seed?

Tags: python, random

So I have a list of 4 strings in Python and I want to return that list, but randomized and only up to a specific number (the variable 'players' in the code below). I CANNOT use the shuffle function, but trust me if I could, I would.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
players = raw_input('How many players? ')
players = int(players)
Roles = ["Role1", "Role2", "Role3", "Role4"]
print Roles[:players]
```

I need to somehow use the random.seed() function to randomize the list. I'm really confused by this, because I thought you could only use random.seed() with numbers, not a list of strings. If anyone could help with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't random.seed() create random numbers starting from one seed number? For this project I have to use random.seed() though.

Comment: Did you notice how the code formatter highlighted `Roles` in blue? It's because names that are upper-case are typically reserved for *Classes*, something much different than a list of strings. Just something to point out for you.

Comment: why can't you use random.shuffle? Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunately homework. I guess it is good practice to understand how to manually shuffle, but I'm just having a little difficulty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) (or `random.sample`) is *The Python Way*, consider using an existing well-known approach if it is truly not an option. The code below is an implementation of the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) (it is adapted from the Sattolo's variant code found on that page):

```
from random import randrange

def shuffle(items):  # mutates input list
    i = len(items)
    while i > 1:
        j = randrange(i)  # 0 <= j <= i
        items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]
        i = i - 1
    return
```

Another approach that is sometimes seen floating about is to zip a list with a sequence of random numbers, sort based on the random numbers, and then extract the original values.

```
from random import random

def shuffle(items):  # returns new list
    return [t[1] for t in
            sorted((random(), i) for i in items)]
```

In any case, `random.seed` merely *sets the seed* for the [PRNG (Pseudo-random number generator)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) used. That is, `random.seed` will affect *future* random numbers generated (and functions which utilize them), but will not itself "get" a random value or "shuffle" or "randomize" anything. (It is usually fine if it is not called, as there is a suitable "default seed" set, but sometimes it's nice - e.g. for repeatability in tests or Solitaire games - to set a particular seed.)

For instance, try this: (If using Python 2.x, remove the parenthesis from the `print`):

```
from random import seed, random

# should all be the same value, whatever that is.
seed(1)
print(random())
seed(1)
print(random())
seed(1)
print(random())

# should be two different values (and different from above)
print(random())
print(random())

# should be same as first three values
seed(1)
print(random())
```

The key to understand is a *PSEUDO RANDOM* source (PRNG) takes the CURRENT internal state - which can be set with a "seed", although a modern PRNG has a *much larger* internal state - and uses that to generate a random value *and* the NEXT internal state. A *TRUE RANDOM* source (e.g. specialty hardware that samples static noise) does not have the concept of a "seed".

Happy coding.

Comment: I used your sorted tuple approach today. Funny how the timing worked out. Just saw this answer the other day.

Comment: Don't you mean `0 <= j < i`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that doesn't use `random.seed` (it's an unusual request for this sort of task), but at the same time, it **doesn't** use `random.shuffle`, either.

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> roles = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4']
>>> players = 3
>>> p = roles[:players]
>>> p
['P1', 'P2', 'P3']
>>> first = choice(p)
>>> p.remove(first)
>>> p
['P1', 'P2']
>>> second = choice(p)
>>> p.remove(second)
>>> p
['P1']
>>> last = choice(p)
>>> p.remove(last)
>>> p
[]
>>> (first, second, last)
('P3', 'P2', 'P1')
```

So, it just so happened that `choice` selected the elements of `p` in reverse order. In a larger pool of candidates in the sequence, this is *far* less likely.

```
>>> l = range(1000)
>>> f = choice(l)
>>> f
967
```

Hopefully you can find a way to incorporate `random.seed`, but personally, I don't see a very good argument for it (see `@pst`'s) answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
players = raw_input('How many players? ')
players = int(players)
roles = ["Role1", "Role2", "Role3", "Role4"]
selected_roles = random.sample(roles[:players], players)
print selected_roles
```